# React fetch tutorial not working after change

Tags: reactjs

I am working through a tutorial for react api's and want to apply my knowledge to some real world applications.

The tutorial uses https://randomuser.me/ for its api call.

their api provides a json feed:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "9278 new road",
        "city": "kilcoole",
        "state": "waterford",
        "postcode": "93027",
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "20.9267",
          "longitude": "-7.9310"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "-3:30",
          "description": "Newfoundland"
        }
      },
      "email": "brad.gibson@example.com",
      "login": {
        "uuid": "155e77ee-ba6d-486f-95ce-0e0c0fb4b919",
        "username": "silverswan131",
        "password": "firewall",
        "salt": "TQA1Gz7x",
        "md5": "dc523cb313b63dfe5be2140b0c05b3bc",
        "sha1": "7a4aa07d1bedcc6bcf4b7f8856643492c191540d",
        "sha256": "74364e96174afa7d17ee52dd2c9c7a4651fe1254f471a78bda0190135dcd3480"
      },
      "dob": {
        "date": "1993-07-20T09:44:18.674Z",
        "age": 26
      },
      "registered": {
        "date": "2002-05-21T10:59:49.966Z",
        "age": 17
      },
      "phone": "011-962-7516",
      "cell": "081-454-0666",
      "id": {
        "name": "PPS",
        "value": "0390511T"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/75.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/75.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "IE"
    }
```

my component handles that with fetch

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'

class adventureGit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      adventures: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=500')
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
      let adventures = data.results.map((adventure) => {
        return(
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={adventure.results}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={adventure.picture.medium}
                    alt={adventure.name.first}
                    />
              <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
             {adventure.name.first}
             </Card.Title>


              </Card.Body>

              </Card>

        )
      })
      this.setState({adventures: adventures});
      console.log("state", this.state.adventures);
    })
  }
render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4}>
              {this.state.adventures}
        </Col>
       </Row>
    </Container>

  )
}
}
export default adventureGit;
```

I notice that fetch is dropping down to the results. how would i process the following json feed which doesnt have the results part

```
[
    {"MerchantId":62362,"MerchantCampaignName":"Roar Adventures","DateCreated":"2019-03-04T22:46:37.940","DateModified":"2019-11-10T02:30:45.043","SKU":"AT_FR_BURGNDY-GUIDED","Name":"Burgundy Guided Bike Tour","Category":"Cultural & Historical","Description":"Let yourself be guided by a passionate specialist, who will take you through the prestigious places of the Burgundian vineyards over 6 days. Savor the pleasure and the ease of being guided through the lovely landscapes and discover the secrets of Burgundy wines.","Url":"https://t.cfjump.com/13467/p/78371640","OriginalUrl":"https://www.roaradventures.com/tours/burgundy-guided-bike-tour","Image":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640.jpg","Image50":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@50x50.jpg","Image100":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@100x100.jpg","Image120":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@120x120.jpg","Image200":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@200x200.jpg","Image300":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@300x300.jpg","Image400":"https://c.cfjump.com/Products/62362/78371640@400x400.jpg","Price":"2022.87","Brand":"","Colour":"","Currency":"EUR","DeliveryCost":"","DeliveryTime":"","Features":"Local English speaking cycling leader/guide. Vehicle support while cycling. All accommodations included. Meals (as indicated in itinerary). 3 visits and wine tastings at local wine estates. Bike and helmet. Luggage transfers . Detailed maps and route suggestions. Hotel taxes. Assistance in case of problems.","Gender":"","Genre":"","Keywords":"france, cultural & historical, romantic, multi-activity, bicycle tour, bicycle adventure, bicycle travel, roar adventures","ContentRating":"G","ModelNumber":"","Platform":"","PriceRrp":"2090.00","PriceSale":"2022.87","PromoText":"","Size":"","StockLevel":"Confirmation Required","SubCategory":"","Custom1":"Burgundy, France","Custom2":"Europe","Custom3":"France","Custom4":""},
```

my assupmtion was to:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://dashboard.commissionfactory.com/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/g_WM6Y_oj-nH4cLo1L2Y65v8jeCV75_ti-uC9NbqkLut6Kv-uOOn7a-8oOy9-a7qv7q98rvxqPusuL2_4Paiq43hw-2c58zw3P7dkqGVv1o=/')
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    }).then(data => {
      let adventures = data.map((adventure) => {
        return(
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={adventure.data}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={adventure.Image400}
                    alt={adventure.Description}
                    />
              <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
             {adventure.Description}
             </Card.Title>


              </Card.Body>

              </Card>

        )
      })
      this.setState({adventures: adventures});
      console.log("state", this.state.adventures);
    })
  }
```

but nothin shows then.

can you show me the error of my ways :)

your help is greatly appreciated

Update:

I added mode:'no-cors' as a result of what i found with @Y.M's answer

```
fetch('https://dashboard.commissionfactory.com/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/g_WM6Y_oj-nH4cLo1L2Y65v8jeCV75_ti-uC9NbqkLut6Kv-uOOn7a-8oOy9-a7qv7q98rvxqPusuL2_4Paiq43hw-2c58zw3P7dkqGVv1o=/', {
      mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
    })
```

and now get.

×

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input
(anonymous function)
src/components/Adventure.js:20
  17 |   mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
  18 | }).then(data => {
  19 |   console.log(data);
> 20 |   const jsonData = data.json();
     | ^  21 |   console.log(jsonData);
  22 |   return jsonData;
  23 | }).then(data => {
```

Update

Access to fetch at 'https://api.rezdy.com/v1/products?apiKey=xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What does this mean?

Comment: I think the problem is `key={adventure.data}`. Your JSON file doesn't contain `data`. You can alternatively use `key={adventure.MerchantId}`

Comment: Can you console log data, data.json() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help on the internets and stackoverflow I found that my issue was not my code as such but cors

Access to fetch at 'https://api.rezdy.com/v1/products?apiKey=xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

with the help of this post i was able to add a proxy and by changing my fetch code to something like this everything worked

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://example.com"; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
fetch(proxyurl + url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're getting data from the server. Please share your data by adding console log at the point.

```
fetch('https://dashboard.commissionfactory.com/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/g_WM6Y_oj-nH4cLo1L2Y65v8jeCV75_ti-uC9NbqkLut6Kv-uOOn7a-8oOy9-a7qv7q98rvxqPusuL2_4Paiq43hw-2c58zw3P7dkqGVv1o=/')
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  const jsonData = data.json();
  console.log(jsonData);
  return jsonData;
}).then(...
```

Comment: updated to show what happens when i add your answer